# How to store 3D matrix in text file so that it can be imported to Matlab?

Tags: c++, matlab, io

I have a text file as an output of a c++ program. Its actually a 3x100x200 element matrix. 3x100 2d matrices over 200 timestamps. I want to store this such that I can load it in Matlab workspace and then visualize it in a 3d plot. I am not able to figure out the structure of the text file. As in where should I put a "[..]" and where ";" and where a " " or ",".

Could someone please give an example so that I can print out in the file from the c++ code in a that manner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a hack without using any extra libs.
I just output every 2d matrix as outMat(:,:,matIndex) and incremented matIndex in a loop. And then I ran the .m in matlab as a script.

```
void printArrs(){
    int i;
//  B(:,:,1) = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
//  B(:,:,2) = [7 8 9; 0 0 0];
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open ("forPlot.m", ios::out | ios::app);
    matIndex++;
    outFile << "outMat(:,:," << matIndex << ") = [";
    for(i=0;i<fftLen;i++){
        outFile << Mag[0][i] << " ";
        outFile << Mag[1][i] << " ";
        outFile << Mag[2][i] << ";" << endl;
    }
    outFile << "];" << endl;
    outFile.close();
}
```

Thanks everyone for your answers.
For some answers I wasnt clear enough I guess, because they assumed I want to write 'from' Matlab and not 'to' Matlab while it was the other way.

Comment: If you are referring to my answer, I just wrote the matlab script so that you can look at the `data.txt` generated in matlab and produce the same looking thing in C++. That is simple. The point is you have to write 2D arrays and reshape. But its true that you can simply write an .m file :) Good job. Although think about binary output for larger matrices. It is **much** faster.

Answer (score 4):

Forget the text file. Instead, write a `.mat` file using the [Matio library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matio/). This way you will be able to quickly add some more data fields in case you need to.

If you really want to use a text file, you can first write the matrix dimensions, then all the elements, and finally do some reshaping as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6367095/19254).

Answer (score 1):

Try googling ".csv" to find out what a comma separated variable file is. That should help, you can import them into Matlab if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to use text files, although I suggest you go for the earlier mentioned Matio library, you can save a 3D array by reshaping it to 2D to write, and by reshaping it to 3d after you read. Have a look at this simple MATLAB code. It writes a 3D matrix to a csv file. After writing, the csv file contains a 2D matrix with the second and third dimensions streamed as a vector:

```
A = rand(3,10,10);
csvwrite('data.txt', A);

B = csvread('data.txt');
% B is now 3 x 100 matrix, so you need to reshape
B = reshape(B, 3, 10, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to save it to a .mat file. You won't have to bother with the file structure this way.
See the documentation of the [save](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/save.html) function. **Edit**: I misread the question and didn't realize you're trying to save the matrix in C++. I suggest you follow Pukku's advice and use the Matio library.

To [load](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/load.html) a .mat file in Matlab, just use

```
load('myfile.mat')
```

Which will put the matrix in your workspace.

Comment: But isn't the OP writing from a C++ program? Anyway, I have enjoyed writing .mat files in my C++ programs using the Matio library, http://sourceforge.net/projects/matio/

Comment: @Pukku: You're right, I somehow skipped over 'C++' in the question. But Matio seems very useful.